# react google map returns empty element _ react

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

this is my react Map component.

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';


this.state = {
            center: {
                lat: 59.95,
                lng: 30.33
            },

        }
<div  style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', position:"absolute" }}>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "some token" }}
                    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                    defaultZoom={16}
                >  
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
```

but nothing renders .why? in github page documentation they said parrent element must have an absolute position with '100vh', width: '100%'. nothing shows On page .

Comment: Well `defaultCenter={this.props.center}` is most likely undefined. Guess you want to change that to `defaultCenter={this.state.center}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'

const SomeText = ({ text }) => <div>{ text }</div>;

<div className='google-map' style={{width:'100%',height:'400px',margin:'auto'}}>
    <GoogleMapReact defaultCenter={ this.props.center } defaultZoom={16}>
        <SomeText lat={ this.props.center.lat } lng={ this.props.center.lng } text={ 'Here you are?' } />
    </GoogleMapReact>
</div>
```

[My map doesn't appear!](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react)

Make sure the container element has width and height. The map will try to fill the parent container, but if the container has no size, the map will collapse to 0 width / height. This is not a requirement for google-map-react, its a requirement for google-maps in general.